# JBoss ESB stop working or logging after startup

Tags: jboss, service, esb

I am using JbossESB as an integrasion layer between applications. I am reading messages from the file system, parse them and then sent them to the remote application by jms.

My configuration file - jboss-esb.xml

```
<fs-provider name="SitaIstProvider">
```

the thing is when JbossESB is starting everything is going ok. But after startup there will be no log entry about this action, although the files are moved from INOUTDIR to OKDIR without any log entry.

Is something wrong with my listener or logger, i don't know? but i do know that there are couple of services working on ESB and they are working just fine and making entries into the log file.

Thannks.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the missing configuration details, here are the nissing configurations.

```
<fs-provider name="MyProvider">
        <fs-bus busid="gw_xaxa_ist" >
            <fs-message-filter
                directory="INPUTDIR"
                input-suffix=".RCV"
                work-suffix=".lck"
                post-delete="false"
                post-directory="OKDIR"
                post-suffix=".ok"
                error-delete="false"
                error-directory="ERRORDIR"
                error-suffix=".err"/>
        </fs-bus>
    </fs-provider>

<services>
    <service category="XAXA" name="XAXA_IST" description="XAXA Daemon">     
        <listeners>
            <fs-listener name="Xaxa_Ist_Gateway" busidref="gw_xaxa_ist" is-gateway="true" schedule-frequency="20" />
            <jms-listener name="Jms_Xaxa_EsbAware" busidref="esb_xaxa_queue" />
        </listeners>

        <actions mep="OneWay">
            <action name="parse_msg" class="com.xaxa.XaxaHandler" process="parseMessage" />
            <action name="send_myapp" class="com.xaxa.integration.action.outbound.MyJmsSender" />
        </actions>
    </service>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend that you add a SystemPrintln action to your actions section. I had quite the same issue.

```
<action name="before_parse" class="org.jboss.soa.esb.actions.SystemPrintln">
   <property name="message" value="Started parsing..." />
</action>
```

On the other hand it might also help to change the log level, but that might increase the log output quite tremendously.

Cheers